# What will happen if I use the sendTextMessage method and the user has a tablet?(Android)

Tags: android, sms, telephony

I want to send an **SMS** message in my application and I want to ask what will happen if the user has a tablet. Will my app crash?
Will it do something strange?

I am using the following method:

```
SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(destinationAddress, scAddress, text, sentIntent, deliveryIntent)
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically, tablet device won't be able to "find" your application from Google play store, since your app requires telephony features.

However, if tablet user got your application some other way, and install it manually, you can not prevent them. When application running, it might crash if the firmware does not handle the exception correctly. But I don't think it would happen, most of the chance it won't take any effect.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that depends on the tablet, if it has a SMS slot or not, I assume you are interested in the type that doesn't has a slot, in this case the tablet will take a long time and the system will ask for wait or cancel, if wait then it will finally show an error message, the error message depends on the Android version, and your application crashes in this case...